# State monad and strategy pattern

Tags: design-patterns, f#, strategy-pattern, state-monad

I am redesigning a library and I am not happy with the current design pattern.
This question concerns the use of the [strategy pattern](http://fsharp3sample.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Strategy%20pattern) in conjunction with a [State monad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5184583/eliminating-my-explicit-state-passing-via-like-monads-and-stuff)

I have a `Filter`. All it does, in its basic implementation, is to take a some datafeed of type `'d` and update itself, generating a new updated copy of itself.

```
[<AbstractClass>]
type Filter<'d, 'F> (state: 'F) =
    member val StateVariable = state with get
    abstract member Update: 'd -> Filter<'d, 'F>
```

I have then a `ISignalGenerator`, that takes a filter, environmental data and process it to generate a `Signal` of type `'S`.

```
type ISignalGenerator<'d, 'F, 'S> =
    abstract member GenerateSignal: 'd -> Filter<'d,'F> -> 'S
```

The `SignalGenerator` is a strategy pattern object. On `SignalGenerator`'s implementations, the library user mounts the functions that will be used and combined to generate the `Signal`.

I could wrap my code in a [state monad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5184583/eliminating-my-explicit-state-passing-via-like-monads-and-stuff). Together with some environmental variables (the datafeed), the state monad will carry carry along 'Filter' as state. `SignalGenerator` will then get state updates via the state monad (the datafeed of type `'d` and the `Filter`)

The design issue I have is that I'd like to decouple the `SignalGenerator` type from the development of the workflow, i.e. I'd like to avoid nesting the state monad in the belly of the `SignalGenerator`. Is there a functional design pattern to achieve this?

**EDIT**

Based on Tomas's comment, I have worked on a toy model.
The choice of having a strategy class is based on the need to wrap together a number of functions.

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Definition of the state 
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
type StateFunc<'State, 'T> = 'State -> 'T * 'State
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Definition of the State monad type
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
type StateMonadBuilder<'State>() =

    // M<'T> -> M<'T>
    member b.ReturnFrom a : StateFunc<'State, 'T> = a

    // 'T -> M<'T>
    member b.Return a : StateFunc<'State, 'T> = ( fun s ->  a, s)

    // M<'T> * ('T -> M<'U>) -> M<'U>
    member b.Bind(p : StateFunc<_, 'T>, rest : 'T -> StateFunc<_,_>) : StateFunc<'State, 'U>  = 
        (fun s ->
            let a, s' = p s
            rest a s')

    // Getter for the whole state, this type signature is because it passes along the state & returns the state
    member b.getState : StateFunc<'State, _> = (fun s -> s, s)

    // Setter for the state
    member b.putState (s:'State) : StateFunc<'State, _> = (fun _ -> (), s)

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// The actual example
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

let state = StateMonadBuilder<int> ()

// DoubleFunctOne defines standard operations that remain always the same
type Strategy (functOne) =
    member this.DoubleFunctOne (x: int) = state {
        let! res = functOne x
        return res * 2 }

// I introduce customization with the definition of this function.
// Whenever I need, I will swap the function with some other   
let myFunctOne x = state {        
    let someOtherFun x = x + 10 
    let! currState = state.getState
    return currState * someOtherFun x}

// Here I mount the custom function on the strategy class, so the Strategy.DoubleFunctOne can produce a result
// In order to do so, I need to keep the construction in the state monad 
let strategy1 = state {
    return Strategy (myFunctOne) }

// Here begins the client side. The client will consume the methods provided by my strategies.
// He should not be concerned by the construction of the strategies
// Ok, then, let's put our work in production
let test1 = (state {
    let! strategy = strategy1
    return! strategy.DoubleFunctOne 10 }) 9
```

I was wondering if there would be a pattern solution where the `Strategy` class could consume the mounted functions without nesting the state monad in its belly. In other words, is there a way to postpone the definition of the `let state = StateMonadBuilder<int> ()`, without landing in a type inference headache?

I am relatively new to functional programming and F#. Please let me know if my question even makes sense! Thanks.

Comment: This is a hard question to answer, because it is talking about the details of your design without explaining what the high-level problem is. I think that if you explain how you get to the design that you currently have, people might be able to give you more useful answers. (In other words, I have no clue what you're trying to do here...)

Comment: This **[XY-questions-post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)** will help you to improve your question.

Comment: I tried it with `let state = StateMonad<_>()` and the rest of the example worked. I also could leave out all other type annotations and just let type inference do it's work. Is that what you mean?

Comment: It's unclear to me why the state monad is necessary or useful here. Why can't you just pass a function as an argument?